# "John mentors many people" -- mentors gets flagged (spelling?)

Tags: transitive-verbs

There are many people mentored by John.  I want to say "John mentors many people", but the word "mentors" gets flagged by MS Word. I can't find an example of this form of mentor.  I think I'll go ahead and ignore the flag.  Comments?

Comment: "I can't find an example of this form of mentor." What, do you mean the verb form? It should be in pretty much every dictionary.

Comment: We can't answer the question of why Microsoft Word is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  I see now that https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-mentor.html has "he/she/it mentors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go ahead."mentors" is fine here.

Comment: Mentors is a noun and transitive verb

Comment: Somebody answered and comments were made and he commented that mentors was plural.  I told him that in this usage, mentors is indicative-present-third person-singular-masculine (verb).  See https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-mentor.html.  He deleted his answer.  It seems this site is great fun.